# Is there any way to select particular portion of column using row index range in Pandas DataFrame using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

for example:
lets say we have a data frame named as students, where the column

```
index  name    value.  name
    0   a    0.469112  jai
    1   b   -0.282863  pria
    2   c   -1.509059  riya
    3   d   -1.135632  avantika 
    4   e    1.212112  Akashi
    5   f   -0.173215  conan
    6   g    0.119209  ai chan
    7   h   -1.044236  shinichi
    8   i   -0.861849  Edogawa
    9   j   -2.104569  black org
```

Now, I specifically want to select column values that are having rows  in the range 4:8, i.e

```
4   e    1.212112  Akashi
5   f   -0.173215  conan
6   g    0.119209  ai chan
7   h   -1.044236  shinichi
```

I have just started understanding pandas, therefore I have doubt related to this stuff.

Comment: df.iloc[4:8] or the like.  Pandas official docs are good, I recommend giving a read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `set_index` and slicing:

```
>>> df.set_index('index')[4:8].reset_index()
   index name    value.    name.1
0      4    e  1.212112    Akashi
1      5    f -0.173215     conan
2      6    g  0.119209   ai chan
3      7    h -1.044236  shinichi
>>>
```

Or try with conditioning:

```
>>> df[df['index'].lt(8) & df['index'].ge(4)]
   index name    value.    name.1
4      4    e  1.212112    Akashi
5      5    f -0.173215     conan
6      6    g  0.119209   ai chan
7      7    h -1.044236  shinichi
>>>
```

Or just:

```
>>> df[4:8]
   index name    value.    name.1
4      4    e  1.212112    Akashi
5      5    f -0.173215     conan
6      6    g  0.119209   ai chan
7      7    h -1.044236  shinichi
>>>
```

Comment: I understood the 1st and 3rd method, but can you please explain the second one, specifically the working of lt and ge.

Comment: @PriyaSinha The second one filters by if the index columns is lower than 8 and bigger or equal to `4` then it will keep that row.

Comment: @PriyaSinha `lt` means lower than, `ge` means greater or equal

Answer (score 1):

You can use df.iloc[row_start:row_end, col_start:col_end]
For your case, use the below code

```
students.iloc[4:8, :] # to take all columns we don't need to put any number range
```

Answer (score 0):

if `index` is a column in your example and you want the value of `index` between 4 and 7. You can do:

```
df[df['index'].between(4,7)]
```

If you just want to select row 4 to 7, you can do:

```
df.iloc[4:8]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
df[4:8]
```

or

```
df.loc[4:7]
```